# javascript offset width and height in percentage

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a width and height of an image in relation to the 'old' 100% width and height of the body(full screen on opening).

Found a script witch gives the width and height in percentage:

```
thisWidth = Math.round(((content.offsetWidth/
               document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].clientWidth)-0)*100) + '%';
thisHeight = Math.round(((content.offsetHeight/
                document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].clientHeight)-0)*100) + '%';
```

Using this script on window.resize, but it always gives 100% (witch it logical because it recalculates on the new sizes an therefor its's always 100%).

But what I need is the percentage in relation to sizes on opening window so I can resize an image in ratio to the new width and height percentages.

Hoping to be clear enough, if not I want to give it an other shot! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fairly untested, but maybe this will help you. Code comments should give you an idea of what's going on:

```js
// Something to compare to.
const initialWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
const initialHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // Get the width of something else, in this case, the body.  
  const width = document.body.clientWidth;
  const height = document.body.clientHeight;
  
  // Convert to percentages.
  const widthInPercent = Math.round((initialWidth / width) * 100);
  const heightInPercent = Math.round((initialHeight / height) * 100);
  
  // Do something with the results.
  document.body.innerHTML = `Width: ${widthInPercent}% Height: ${heightInPercent}%`;
});
```